# How are pools of HTTPS connections managed?

Tags: networking, https, concurrency

Consider an application that access a remote HTTPS server, sending POST of JSON-formatted requests at an URL on the server, and receiving JSON-formatted answers. The server does not support [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2#Differences_from_HTTP_1.1) multiplexing.

There are many requests, with widely varying workload (from idle to hundreds TPS). JSON messages are in the order of 1 kbyte. Client and server are authenticated by certificates+private keys. The requests can be considered independent (in particular, the server treats requests alike for all HTTPS channels opened with the same client certificate).

HTTP/1.1 does not allow<sup>*</sup> multiple concurrent POST requests over the same connection. Therefore the throughput can't exceed ***N/(Tr+Ts)*** TPS, where ***N*** is the number of opened HTTPS/TLS channels in use, ***Tr*** is the network round trip delay, and ***Ts*** is processing time on the server side (in the order of 30 ms under low load, due to database access and other factors). Opening an HTTPS connection costs at least ***4 Tr***, and sizable CPU time on both sides. It looks like something is needed to manage a pool of HTTPS connections on the client side.

**How is this issue usually handled?**

What are common libraries or background daemon/services, automatically opening new HTTPS connections as needed, reusing them when possible?

It would be nice if that detected when the server becomes unresponsive, and handled fallback to a backup server at a different URL, with return to the main server when it is up again.

Note: Next step would be load balancing, but then my load-balancing layer must somewhat handle an affinity between the requests, since they are not fully independent (sending a dependent request to the wrong server is reliably detected by the server, though).

---

[*] Due to how [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-1.4) is interpreted, I'm [told](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/92769410).

Comment: This would probably give you way better response on stackoverflow, so I'm voting to migrate it there. From an OPS perspective I'd tell my developers to either build stateless apps that can be easily distributed behind a loadbalancer with HTTP2/SPDY support, or atleast manage affinity via session cookies or tokens.

Comment: I doubt the validity of statement that multiple post can't happen on same connection. This is what connection pools are, to reuse the connection. That's what keep-alive headers are there in http to reuse the same connection.

Comment: @Mukesh Verma: multiple **concurent** POST can't happen on the same HTTP(S)/1.1 connection: one hasto wait until the answer of the first to send the second over the same connection. Connection pools are here to solve that issue. That's also solved by HTTP/2 multiplexing, with a single connection.